# How to find UK visa processing times for a specific country/location? Is it possible to withdraw your application and get your passport back early?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens

I'm curious about the processing time for UK Standard Visitor Visa (6 month) for my specific location (Tokyo VAC). I know there used to exist an [website](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y) where you could check this but I guess its gone now?

Additionally is it possible to withdraw your application early, in case you need to travel somewhere else and need your passport while the application is still in processing hell

Answer (score 1):

The visa processing for UK is done centrally and usually there won't be much difference between the locations.

Waiting times are listed in this page - https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visa-decision-waiting-times-applications-outside-the-uk

Which is currently, within 3 weeks.

There is an option to keep the passport with you till a decision is reached, for an additional payment. Also, there is priority visa options available.

You can always request your passport back, in case of emergency travel.